# Existing entities loss their parent after updating the parent

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Here is a parent structure of entity classes with one-to-one and one-to-many relationships in a Spring Boot application:

```
@Entity
@SuppressWarnings("common-java:DuplicatedBlocks")
public class A implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "a" }, allowSetters = true)
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private B b;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "a" }, allowSetters = true)
  private List<C> cs = new ArrayList<>();

   ...
}

@Entity
@SuppressWarnings("common-java:DuplicatedBlocks")
public class b implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @JsonIgnoreProperties(
    value = { "b", "cs", ... },
    allowSetters = true
)
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    private A a;
 // ..
}

@Entity
@SuppressWarnings("common-java:DuplicatedBlocks")
public class C implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(
    value = { "b", "cs", ...},
    allowSetters = true
)
  private A a;

 // ...
}
```

I use aRepository.save(a) to save a new instance of entity A. It is excellent because one save method call takes care of all data resistance of its children entities.

When it comes to updating the set of entity data, there is a problem with one-to-many relationships. I do the following for the update operation

```
A oldA = ... ; // from the DB
A newA = ...; // new data
newA.setId(oldA.getId);
B newB = ...;
newB.setA(newA);
newB.setId(oldB.getId());
newA.setB(newB);

List<C> cList = ...; // new data
newA.setCs(cList);

aRepository.save(newA);
```

That works fine other than entity C data. Entity B is updated. And that new entity C data are also inserted into the DB table. However, the existing entity C data lose its parent. The parent column of those data becomes blank. What is the right approach for this type of update? Shall I do this type of update by using the repository of each entity?

Comment: They do not 'lose' their parent - you just haven't set their parent in your code. It is Cs reference to A that controls the foriegn key in the database, so if you want it to be set there, you have to set it in your C instances - you are responsible for setting both sides of bidirectional relationships to keep them in synch as JPA (or JSON) won't do it for you. Ensure that your list of C instances have their a property set to point to the parent A before you save it and it'll work

Comment: In the update operation, I didn't touch the existing entity C at all.

Comment: That's my point. You need to ensure C references A or the database won't have the reference table set. One side owns the bidirectional relationship, which means in JPA, that is the reference that controls setting the foreign key. You are essentially setting the 'wrong' side with the current mapping setup and leaving the side that controls the relationship null. Technically you should be setting both sides of this bidirectional relationship so that the object model reflects what you want in the database, and this is what happens when one side is out of synch with the other

Comment: Why did you set both sides of the A-B relationship and not expect to have to do the same with the A-C relationship?

Comment: For the update, entity B has a replacement of the existing data. But, entity C has a new set of data in addition to those existing data. That was my reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bidirectional relationship and you are setting only one side (A's list of Cs), leaving C's references to As blank/null. Since both sides are out of synch with each other, JPA will use the owning side to determine what to put into the database. In this case, you have everything mapped within A as owned by the other side.

Your relationship between A-B is being set because you are setting both sides:

```
newB.setA(newA);
newA.setB(newB);
```

If you want this to work, you need to set C's reference to A in the same way:

```
newA.setCs(cList);
cList.stream().forEach( c -> c.setA(newA) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for a benefit of others who run into the same situation.

I end up using repositories of children with one-to-many relationships to save new child data to overcome the lazy collection isn't initiated error.